# Как сделать такую кнопку в своем android приложении?

Tags: xml, android-studio

Хотелось бы сделать подобную кнопку, но не совсем понимаю как. Понимаю, что можно сделать кликабельной imageview, но в то же время нужно, чтобы под ним было описание[image: Та самая кнопка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ 1:**

Создайте контейнер (LinearLayout) с вертикальной ориентацией, поместите в него ImageView и TextView. Слушатель вешайте на контейнер.

**Способ 2:**

Воспользуйтесь возможностью добавить картинку к любому View слева, справа, сверху и/или снизу с помощью атрибута `android:drawableTop` (Left, Bottom, Right)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Первый способ лучше, т.к. у вас будет больше контроля над тем как должна выглядеть и располагаться картинка

Comment: А зачем вы добавили id `LikeCount?`

Comment: @P.Ilyin, с гугла копипастил и пропустил)

Comment: а при использовании первого способа, текст, на разных экранах смартфонов, не будет смещаться?

Comment: @A.Schtolc, тут уж как настроите... Проставьте нужную вам layout_gravity для текста и всё...

Comment: а если пользоваться вторым способом, то картинку кликабельной никак не сделать?

Comment: @A.Schtolc, ну... Сделать её кликабельной можно, но только аццким костылём. Если хотите кликабельной сделать - используйте первый способ.

Answer (score 0):

Использование свойства `drawableTop` у `TextView` может стать хорошим решением:

```
<TextView
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/some_drawable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="123"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff55ff" />
```

Comment: Извините, если я задаю глупый вопрос, но как при этом сделать саму картинку кликабельной?